# why mtrace utility is not supporting mmap() allocations?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, mtrace

Why Linux mtrace utility is not tracking memory allocations done through mmap() / munmap() cals ?  How and What are the challenges in implementing that ?

I need a reliable tool to track memory allocations done by my application which heavily uses mmap() calls.  valgrind cannot support my setuid enabled application, and emits this error 'Can't execute setuid/setgid executable  :: Valgrind does not support setuid executables.'

Thanks,
Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which utility of mtrace you are using. But for nmap the mtrace has different utility provided that http://nmap.org. You have to download that utility which is avaiable at http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/mtrace.html. Providing following description

> > Queries for the multicast path from a source to a destination host.
> >
> > This works by sending an IGMP Traceroute Query and listening for IGMP Traceroute responses. The Traceroute Query is sent to the first hop and contains information about source, destination and multicast group addresses. First hop defaults to the multicast All routers address. The default multicast group address is 0.0.0.0 and the default destination is our own host address. A source address must be provided. The responses are parsed to get interesting information about interface addresses, used protocols and error codes.
> >
> > This is similar to the mtrace utility provided in Cisco IOS.

Comment: I think, you meant mtrace for 'multicast trace'.  My question is for 'memory tracing' utility provided by GNU in Linux.